# Create a list with multiple data entries per index

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm looking for a way in VB.net of creating some kind of index list of servers, so that I can access their names and IP Addresses on the fly. I've looked at both the List Class and Dictionary object, but I'm not sure if they would be able to do the job in this case.

Basicaly, I'd like a structure similar to this when I declare `ServersList` -

```
chkTTSA - Name = TTSA
          IPAddress = 192.168.1.6
chkTTSB - name = TTSA
          IPAddress = 192.168.1.7
```

Then when I am accessing data by looping through a Dictionary, I'd like to use the name and IP address in `ServerList` to populate another Dictionary -

```
ServersToPing(ServersList(Name)) = ServersList(IPAddress)
```

Currently, I'm using a `Dictionary` for both `Name` and `IPAddress`, but in the future I'd like to add more server information, so having to use a `Dictionary` for each seems like it would be inefficient.

I'm not sure if this is possible in the exact way I would like, but I'd be grateful if someone could give me some pointers as to how I'd achieve my goal.

Comment: So you want one dictionary with the IP-Adresses as key and another with the servernames as keys?
What have you tried, how do you want to populate them?

Comment: Ideally I'd like just one list that contains both. I'm currently using 2x `Dictionary`, but it's a bit of a hassle, and I'm looking for ways that may be more efficient. In the future, for example, I may want to add things like `ServerLocation`, `ServerOS`, `ServerMemory`, etc, so having a `Dictionary` for each seems like hard work.

Comment: But it would be the most efficient approach if you want to lookup all these values. However, you should create a class which contains all properties(e.g. Name,IP,OS,Memory, etc). Then you can use it as value in the dictionary(ies).

Comment: possible duplicate of [List with multiple indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143773/list-with-multiple-indexes)

Comment: Maybe you could use the old fashioned DataTable and use LinQ to search for your values

Comment: Thanks for the reply's guys, I'll have a look at the options and then update the question, as it is probably a bit vague. I'm liking the idea of a Class though, so may go down that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the helpful comments, I was able to devise a method of achieving what I require through use of a Class.

This method is scalable, and will allow me to easily add more information in the future, as and when it is required

```
Partial Public Class SingleServer

    Public ReadOnly Name As String
    Public ReadOnly IPAddress As String
    Public ReadOnly Ping As Boolean

    '**
    ' Constructor
    '*
    Public Sub New(SingleName As String, SingleIPAddress As String, Optional SinglePing As Boolean = False)

        Name = SingleName
        IPAddress = SingleIPAddress
        Ping = SinglePing

    End Sub

End Class
```

To use, I first initialise an instance of the SingleServer Object...

```
Public ReadOnly ServersList As New Dictionary(Of String, SingleServer)
```

...And then I can add the information as desired...

```
ServersList("chkTTSA") = New SingleServer("TTSA", "192.168.1.6")
```

In the future, I may wish to declare the servers through a text file and have the program add the necessary checkboxs, as opposed to explicitly declaring them as I do know, and this method will also allow me to do that.